# Show report parameter on report Oracle APEX 4.2

Tags: oracle-apex

I have the following query in region source

```
select PROPERTY.CODE as CODE,
    PROPERTY.NAME as NAME,
    PROPERTY.LOCATION as LOCATION,
    :P26_PStart as Start
 from PROPERTY PROPERTY
WHERE PROPERTY.CODE=:P26_PROPERTY
```

While I want to show parameter on report but it does now show as report column in report

Comment: In the columns section of your report, is START listed?

Comment: yes it showing there

Comment: I have a similiar case, that is working for me (APEX 5). I can only recommend taking the line `:P26_PStart as Start` out and back in again, try to rearrange the columns, check _Page Items to Submit_, or try what happens with other items or constants.

Comment: its working fine but not showing this start column in report

Comment: Now it works when I have run it again after browser restart

Comment: Ok, good for you! :)

Comment: I know its been a while since you asked but, I don't understand your question. You don't want to be listed as a column but as an item in the same region?

Comment: I have run it again after browser restart, so issue get resolved